# ASP.NET web site starts asking for login when javascript opens new page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I manage a web site that provides functionality to customers registered on the site. The site was developed over 10 years ago in ASP.NET. When a customer enters an order, after completion they can print the order if they select the Print Order button. This button fires a java script function that opens the print order page in a new tab and fills the page with the order data. The order data is provided through the Get info appended to the url. This has worked for a long time. Recently our hosting service moved us to a new server running the latest version of Windows server. Now when the user selects the print order button the login page comes up with a link to the print page after the user re-logs in. I can't figure out what has changed and how to get the original functionality back. Both the Order input page and the print order page are in the same folder on the site.

The url of the page that should open is: http://www.sitename.com/Customer%2fPrintOrderFilling.aspx%PostData

What we are getting now is: http://www.sitename.com/login/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fCustomer%2fPrintOrderFilling.aspx%PostData

Comment: You can try to use failed request trace to see detailed information.

Comment: Solved the issue. Changed link to relative addressing from an absolute address.